# Lazily fetching entity with multiple relations: Could not write JSON: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, lazy-loading, entitygraph

```
Message Could not write JSON: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: core.domain.Cat.catFoods, could not initialize proxy - no Session; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: core.domain.Cat.catFoods, could not initialize proxy - no Session (through reference chain: web.dto.ToysDTO["toys"]->java.util.HashSet[0]->web.dto.ToyDTO["cat"]->core.domain.Cat["catFoods"])

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.
```

I have the following entities: Toy, Cat, CatFood and Food. Basically Cat with Toy are in 1:1 relation and Cat and Food are in m:n relation using CatFood.

```java
@NamedEntityGraphs({
        @NamedEntityGraph(name = "toyWithCat",
                attributeNodes = @NamedAttributeNode(value = "cat"))
})
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
@ToString
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@Entity
public class Toy extends BaseEntity<Long> {
    String name;
    int size;

    public Toy(Long id, String name, int size) {
        this.setId(id);
        this.name = name;
        this.size = size;
    }

    @JsonBackReference(value = "cat-reference")
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "favoriteToy")
    private Cat cat;

}
```

```java
@NamedEntityGraphs({
        @NamedEntityGraph(name = "catWithToy",
                attributeNodes = @NamedAttributeNode(value = "favoriteToy")),
        @NamedEntityGraph(name = "catWithCatFoodAndFood",
                attributeNodes = @NamedAttributeNode(value = "catFoods",
                        subgraph = "catFoodWithFood"),
                subgraphs = @NamedSubgraph(name = "catFoodWithFood",
                        attributeNodes = @NamedAttributeNode(value = "food")))
})
@Entity
public class Cat extends BaseEntity<Long> {
    String name, breed;
    Integer catYears;
    @JsonManagedReference(value = "cat-reference")
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "toy_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Toy favoriteToy;

    @JsonManagedReference(value = "cat-reference")
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "cat", cascade = {CascadeType.REMOVE}, orphanRemoval = true)
    Set<CatFood> catFoods;
```

And I am trying to call this function

```java
public interface ToyRepository extends Repository<Toy, Long> {
    @Query("select distinct t from Toy t")
    @EntityGraph(value = "toyWithCat", type = EntityGraph.EntityGraphType.LOAD)
    List<Toy> getToysWithCat();
}
```

I am using the same idea on fetching cats with toys as the toy entity does not have another relation and they are loaded without a problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `Toy` class you are using `@EqualsAndHashCode` which will be resolved in an `hashCode()` implementation calculating the hashCode based on all properties of that class.

That means that the hashCode method in your `Toy` class invokes the `hasCode` method on `Cat`. In cat there is a `Set` of `CatFoods` which is mapped by `Cat` which means that to calculate the `hashCode` of `catFoods` the `Cat` property is involved. To calculate the hashCode of Cat it begins again calculating the `hashCode` of the `Set` of `CatFoods`

*(Sounds confusing but currently I am unable to describe it better)*

As there is no session active the Lazy collection can not be fetched which is required to calculate the hashCod. Thats why you get this exception.

Takeaway: explicitly exclude `LAZY` fetched properties from `@EqualsAndHashCode` calculation. You can annotate these properties using `@EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude` to exclude them from the hashCode calculation.

To see implementation of the hashCode calculation you can use the DeLombok functionality of IntelliJ.